# In Agda is it possible to define a datatype that has equations?

Tags: agda, algebraic-data-types

I want to describe the integers:

```
data Integer : Set where
    Z : Integer
    Succ : Integer -> Integer
    Pred : Integer -> Integer
    ?? what else
```

The above does not define the Integers.  We need Succ (Pred x) = x and Pred (Succ x) = x.  However,

```
    spReduce : (m : Integer) -> Succ (Pred m) = m
    psReduce : (m : Integer) -> Pred (Succ m) = m
```

Can't be added to the data type.  A better definition of the integers is most certainly,

```
data Integers : Set where
    Pos : Nat -> Integers
    Neg : Nat -> Integers
```

But I am curious if there is a way to add equations to a datatype.

Comment: Note that since 0 is a `Nat`, you'd still have `Pos 0` and `Neg 0` as two redundant representations of the integer 0.

Comment: This is now possible in a highly experimental branch of Agda by using something called Higher Inductive Types from Homotopy Type Theory. These allow you to define equations in addition to constructors for a data type. https://github.com/agda/agda/tree/hits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that what you'd like to do is define your `Integers` type as a quotient type by the equivalence relation that identifies `Succ (Pred m)` with `m`, etc. Agda doesn't support that anymore -- there was an experimental library that tried to do that (by forcing all functions over a quotient type to be defined via a helper function that requires proof of representational invariance), but then someone discovered that the implementation wasn't watertight enough and so could lead to inconsistencies (basically by accessing one of its postulates that was supposed to be inaccessible from the outside), for the details you can see [this message](https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2012/004052.html):

> We were not sure if this hack was sound or not. Now, thanks to Dan
>   Doel, I know that it isn't.
>
> [...]
>
> Given these observations it is easy to prove that the postulate above
>   is unsound:

I think your best bet at the moment (if you want to/need to stick to a loose representation with an equivalency to tighten it up) is to define a `Setoid` for your type..

Answer (score 5):

I'd go about it by defining a `record`:

```
record Integer (A : Set) : Set where
  constructor integer
  field
    z : A
    succ : A -> A
    pred : A -> A
    spInv : (x : A) -> succ (pred x) == x
    psInv : (x : A) -> pred (succ x) == x
```

This record can be used as a proof that a certain type `A` behaves like an `Integer` should.